# How to find rows with timestamp within 30 seconds of each other

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

We have a table of items with "actions" and timestamps.  What I'm trying to do is return a list of all items in this table where the timestamp of one row is within 30 seconds of another row and has the action of 'Approved' and have the same Item Code.

Item Table

```
ID    Title      Code  
---   ---------- ---------
1     Title 1    B35
2     Title 2    A35
3     Title 3    A35
4     Title 4    A35
5     Title 5    A35
6     Title 6    A35
7     Title 7    B17
```

Action Table

```
ID    Action     Timestamp                    ItemId   
---   ---------- -------------------------    --------
1     Submitted   2018-02-27 16:29:52.307     1
2     Approved    2018-02-28 11:06:56.773     2
3     Approved    2018-02-28 11:07:10.773     3
4     Approved    2018-02-28 12:45:09.773     4
5     Approved    2018-03-15 13:36:03.003     5
6     Approved    2018-03-15 13:36:27.003     6
7     Approved    2018-03-15 13:36:28.003     7
```

So for example given the table above it'd tell me rows 2 & 3 and rows 5 & 6, row 7 wouldn't match because the item code on the Item table doesn't match).  I've tried a few things I've seen off of stackoverflow, but would only match the second part of the timestamp and disregard the hour & minute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`, but I would recommend `lag()`/`lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (order by timestamp) as prev_timestamp,
             lead(timestamp) over (order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where timestamp < dateadd(second, 30, prev_timestamp) or
      timestamp > dateadd(second, 30, next_timestamp);
```

On larger data, I would expect this to be faster than `exists`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.  The issue is a bit more complicated than I had originally thought.  I've updated the original post with a couple matching issues I need to take into consideration.

Comment: @makinitmine . . . The query just needs `partition by item_id`.

Comment: @makinitmine . . . Then I don't understand the issue with the original version of the answer.

Comment: The issue with the original is it doesn't take account for the keyed Item table's Code column so it returns matches even if their codes don't match